# Angular 4 handling chain of delete

Tags: angular, subject

I create a ReplaySubject of size 3 and delete chain must be in order. The problem is I should redirect the user when they finish deletion and when I subscribe to this ReplaySubject Method it send "here finish" while still not realy finished deletion in DB.
Which method and how I should handle chain of requests and know exactly when they are finished.

```
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(3 /* buffer size */);
if (allIds.length > 0) {
subject.next(this.cService.delete1(Ids1).subscribe(data => { console.log('deleted 1'); }));
subject.next(this.cService.delete2(Ids2).subscribe(data => { console.log('deleted 2'); }));
subject.next(this.cService.delete3(Ids3).subscribe(data => { console.log('deleted 3'); }));
}
return subject.map(() => { console.log('here finish');  });
```

Comment: Use switchMap to chain observables see e.g. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Comment: what do think? of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853358/angular-subscribe-from-apollo-return-error-is-not-defined @Eliseo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know what is Apollo client or a multi mutation. in my last comment I want to tell you to make some like

```
this.cService.delete1(Ids1)
    .switchMap((data)=>{ //data from delete 1
       console.log('delete 1');
       return this.cService.delete2(Isd2).switchMap((data)=>{  //data from delete 2
             console.log('delete 2');
             return this.cService.delete3(Isd3);
       })
    }).subscribe(data=>{  //data from delete 3
            console.log('delete 3');
            console.log("the end")
    });
```

We only subscribe the last